# What's the official term for $A in Lightning Components?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, variable-names

I understand that this variable can be used to [access component-level information](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_components/lightning_components_events_handle), but I was wondering what the official term for it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a namespace for Javascript API of Aura. Infact top namespace.(If your familiar with apex its almost like system class)

http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:$A

Take a look at Aura documentation for same. Its top level namespace for creation of components, getting a component, setting a component, Enqueuing Action, Running an Action.

Comment: Indeed, as Mohit describes, you can just pronounce $A as "Aura".

Comment: The link isn't accessible

Comment: You can access the Aura documentation through your org. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_doc_app.htm) for details.

Comment: You used to be able to access it through your org, via https://<your-my-domain>.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app, but it's moved again. You can now find it in the Javascript API section under References of the [Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_intro.htm)